Strange code on my Jekyll website sitemap
I'm developing my own portfolio using Jekyll, but when i tried to import my sitemap.xml do Google WebMasters, I got an error, I check the XML and I got this, can somebody please explain why is this happening? And how can I disable this?
https://patoflamejantetv.github.io/PatoFlamejanteTV/sitemap.xml

<script>
{ document.currentScript.dataset.injected = true; const o = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(atob('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')))); if (o.userAgentDataBuilder) { const v = new class NavigatorUAData { #p; constructor({p, ua}) { this.#p = p; const version = p.browser.major; const name = p.browser.name === 'Chrome' ? 'Google Chrome' : p.browser.name; this.brands = [{ brand: name, version }, { brand: 'Chromium', version }, { brand: 'Not=A?Brand', version: '24' }]; this.mobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(ua); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-CH-UA-Platform this.platform = 'Unknown'; if (p.os && p.os.name) { const name = p.os.name.toLowerCase(); if (name.includes('mac')) { this.platform = 'macOS'; } else if (name.includes('debian')) { this.platform = 'Linux'; } else { this.platform = p.os.name; } } } toJSON() { return { brands: this.brands, mobile: this.mobile, platform: this.platform }; } getHighEntropyValues(hints) { if (!hints || Array.isArray(hints) === false) { return Promise.reject(Error("Failed to execute 'getHighEntropyValues' on 'NavigatorUAData'")); } const r = this.toJSON(); if (hints.includes('architecture')) { r.architecture = this.#p?.cpu?.architecture || 'x86'; } if (hints.includes('bitness')) { r.bitness = '64'; } if (hints.includes('model')) { r.model = ''; } if (hints.includes('platformVersion')) { r.platformVersion = this.#p?.os?.version || '10.0.0'; } if (hints.includes('uaFullVersion')) { r.uaFullVersion = this.brands[0].version; } if (hints.includes('fullVersionList')) { r.fullVersionList = this.brands; } return Promise.resolve(r); } }(o.userAgentDataBuilder); navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgentData', () => { return v; }); } delete o.userAgentDataBuilder; for (const key of Object.keys(o)) { if (o[key] === '[delete]') { delete Object.getPrototypeOf(window.navigator)[key]; } else { navigator.__defineGetter__(key, () => { if (o[key] === 'empty') { return ''; } return o[key]; }); } } }
</script>
<url>
<loc>
https://patoflamejantetv.github.io/PatoFlamejanteTV/
</loc>
</url>
</urlset>

Also, the full Jekyll code is here, in case is some plugin's fault: https://github.com/PatoFlamejanteTV/PatoFlamejanteTV/tree/main

I don't have the script tag when visiting that url. Perhaps it's a browser extension? I'd try a different browser.

Most likely, one of your browser plugins is doing this.
